# OpenTripPlanner getting started tutorial error

Tags: maven, gis, geotools, opentripplanner

I'm trying to install OpenTripPlanner following the [official tutorial](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/Install). 
I've correctly cloned the git repository, then I import the project in Eclipse but it is unable to build all the packages. One of the error is "The import org.geotools cannot be resolved" 
So I've tryed with the [Maven tutorial](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/GettingStartedMaven) but when I run "`mvn install integration-test -DskipTests -P interactive`" I get:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.geotools:library:pom:null

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.geotools:modules for project: org.geotools:library:pom:null for project org.geotools:library:pom:null


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 20 15:53:31 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/473M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Googling, I've not found anything similar, so, what's the matter?

Comment: is the version variable set?

Comment: @iant, yes, the code is the same published on Git repository https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/

<geotools.version>8.0-M4</geotools.version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that the geotools.version (and other) properties are not set in the main pom (https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/pom.xml).
Probably the hudson builder is using variables coming from the settings.xml.

Try defining it manually:

```
mvn install integration-test -DskipTests -Pinteractive -Dgeotools.version=9.1 -Dspring.version=3.1.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: If so, please open a bug report on the github site ;)

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! Now I open the bug on github :)